# How to instantiate a Comparator inside of a Constructor

Tags: java, comparator, treemap

I have never seen a comparator created inside of a constructor for a TreeMap structure.  How would one go about doing this?  Is there a way to make the TreeMap() constructor call the other TreeMap constructor which has a comparator argument to set up the comparator?

```
private Comparator<? super K> cmp;
private Node root;
private int size;
private final String indentStr = "   ";

public TreeMap() {
    // Create cmp assuming K implements Comparator
    //???  TreeMap(new Comparator<V>());
}

public TreeMap(Comparator<? super K> cmp) {
    this.cmp = cmp;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They usually set that fields to `null`, rather than instantiating something.

But if you want to, you can have:

```
this(new Comparator<K>() {
   public int compare(K k1, K k2) {
       return ((Comparable<K>) k1).compareTo(k2);
   }
});
```

The problem is that `ClassCastException` can occur, because you don't know the type of the elements.

Comment: How about `return ((Comparable<K>) k1).compareTo(k2);`?

Comment: ClassCastException? You can do that, of course, but it can fail. I added it to the answer anyway